# g++ cannot find symbols when linking

Tags: gcc, linker, g++

OK, this is probably very basic, but I can't find the problem. I'm trying to link my C++ program with a C shared library (YAJL to name it) with -lyajl ; the linker seems to find it (it does not complain for that) but cannot find the symbols I use in my code :

```
$> g++ test.c -lyajl

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "yajl_tree_parse(char const*, char*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      _main in ccEqsAaJ.o
  "yajl_tree_get(yajl_val_s*, char const**, yajl_type)", referenced from:
      _main in ccEqsAaJ.o
  "yajl_tree_free(yajl_val_s*)", referenced from:
      _main in ccEqsAaJ.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
$>
```

I made a minimalist test.c file to isolate the behavior. Well, what's very strange is that  gcc seems perfectly OK with the code (as, incidentally, test.c is just C code, no C++ feature here):

```
$> gcc test.c -lyajl
$>
```

What is gcc doing that g++ doesn't seem to be able to do right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be that the symbols in libyajl.so are C linkage, but your code (or the header file you are using) does not declare them `extern "C"`? In that case, compiling your code as C++ would result in [name-mangled symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B) in your object file, which would not match the (C linkage, unmangled) symbols in the library.

The solution would be to write, in the header file, something like this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
// "__cplusplus" is defined whenever it's a C++ compiler,
// not a C compiler, that is doing the compiling.
extern "C" {
#endif

// Exchange "void" with the real return type for these functions
void yajl_tree_parse(char const*, char*, unsigned long);
void yajl_tree_get(yajl_val_s*, char const**, yajl_type);
void yajl_tree_free(yajl_val_s*);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

If `extern "C"` does not fix it, try this.

I had the same problem trying to link against the static library- libyajl_s.a.
It is possible to work around the problem by compiling the yajl source into the executable,
but I really needed the static library.
On closer inspection of the yajl source you will see that the source is looking for headers in two separate folders, e.g.

`#include <api/yajl_tree.h>`
`#include <api/yajl_parse.h>`
`#include "yajl_parser.h"`

The linker seems to resolve yajl_tree_parse, yajl_tree_get and yajl_tree_free to their prototypes in yajl_tree.h and not to their definitions in yajl_tree.c. In other words- they remain undefined in the resulting library.

The solution was to move all headers from the *api* folder into the *src* folder and remove all references to `<api/...>`. The linker then picked up the yajl_tree_xxx function definitions correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at this too.